# iOS8 Cannot hide cancel button on search bar in UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My goal is to prevent the cancel button from appearing in a search bar in a UISearchController. I started with [Apple's Table Search with UISearchController sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController) and hid the cancel button as seen in the code snip below. However, when the user taps in the text field, the cancel button still appears. Any help?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultsTableController = ResultsTableController()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    //Hide cancel button - added by me
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

    ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think there are three ways of achieving that:

1. Override **searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch** and use the following code:

> `searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false`

2. Subclass UISearchBar and override the layoutSubviews to change that var when the system attempts to draw it.
3. Register for keyboard notification **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and apply the code in point **1.**

Of course can always implement your search bar.

Comment: 1: is deprecated in iOS 8. It's replacement `didPresentSearchController:` gets called after the cancel button is already show, causing a flash. 2: I don't think you can tell `UISearchController` to use a custom subclass of search bar? 3: What about cases where the keyboard isn't shown? For example, if a keyboard is paired/attached?

Comment: +1 for #1. I'm not getting any warnings about depreciation and I see no flashes, seems to work perfectly and thats the solution with the least amount of code.

Answer (score 17):

For iOS 8, and UISearchController, use this delegate method from `UISearchControllerDelegate`:

```
func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
  searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

Don't forget to set yourself as the delegate: `searchController.delegate = self`

Comment: As @jemmons pointed out, this works but causes a flash because we hide the cancel button when it's already there.

Comment: @MichaelPirotte this still flashes as of iOS 9.3.1 .

Answer (score 15):

Simply subclass `UISearchController` & `UISearchBar`.

```
class NoCancelButtonSearchController: UISearchController {
    let noCancelButtonSearchBar = NoCancelButtonSearchBar()
    override var searchBar: UISearchBar { return noCancelButtonSearchBar }
}

class NoCancelButtonSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) { /* void */ }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following github project subclasses UISearchBar which is presented as solution 2:

https://github.com/mechaman/CustomSearchControllerSwift

On top of it, it also subclasses UISearchController to enable one to put the search bar in places other than the tableView header!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This was the simplest solution I could come up with in Swift.

Custom search controller:

```
class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

    var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        self._searchBar = CustomSearchBar()
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override init(searchResultsController: UIViewController?) {
        self._searchBar = CustomSearchBar()
        super.init(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        return self._searchBar
    }
}
```

Custom search bar:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func setShowsCancelButton(showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

The most important piece of this was to only create the `_searchBar` object once in `init` vs. creating it inside of the stored property.

Answer (score 2):

Just subclass your UISearchController and do the following:

```
class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
   }
}
```

This was the easiest solution I could came up with in order to solve the flashing cancel-button issue.

Comment: It works on iOS 12, but has a little jumping animation. :(

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**:
Subclassing `UISearchBar` and overriding `setShowsCancelButton:` and `setShowsCancelButton:animated:` hides the cancel button.

## SOLUTION

I set `active` to `NO` if the search bar is not the first responder (keyboard is not active and displayed), since that is effectively a *cancel* command.

### FJSearchBar

Marking `searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO` doesn't seem to work in **iOS 8**. I haven't tested **iOS 9**.

#### FJSearchBar.h

Empty, but placed here for completeness.

```
@import UIKit;

@interface FJSearchBar : UISearchBar

@end
```

#### FJSearchBar.m

```
#import "FJSearchBar.h"

@implementation FJSearchBar

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    // do nothing
}

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // do nothing
}

@end
```

### FJSearchController

Here's where you want to make the real changes. I split the `UISearchBarDelegate` into its own category because, IMHO, the categories make the classes cleaner and easier to maintain. If you want to keep the delegate within the main class interface/implementation, you're more than welcome to do so.

#### FJSearchController.h

```
@import UIKit;

@interface FJSearchController : UISearchController

@end

@interface FJSearchController (UISearchBarDelegate) <UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

#### FJSearchController.m

```
#import "FJSearchController.h"
#import "FJSearchBar.h"

@implementation FJSearchController {
@private
    FJSearchBar *_searchBar;
    BOOL _clearedOutside;
}

- (UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        // if you're not hiding the cancel button, simply uncomment the line below and delete the FJSearchBar alloc/init
        // _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar = [[FJSearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

@end

@implementation FJSearchController (UISearchBarDelegate)

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // if we cleared from outside then we should not allow any new editing
    BOOL shouldAllowEditing = !_clearedOutside;
    _clearedOutside = NO;
    return shouldAllowEditing;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // hide the keyboard since the user will no longer add any more input
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // the user cleared the search while not in typing mode, so we should deactivate searching
        self.active = NO;
        _clearedOutside = YES;
        return;
    }
    // update the search results
    [self.searchResultsUpdater updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self];
}

@end
```

Some parts to note:

1. I've put the search bar and the `BOOL` as private variables instead of properties because

   - They're more lightweight than private properties.
   - They don't need to be seen or modified by the outside world.
2. We check whether the `searchBar` is the first responder. If it's not, then we actually deactivate the search controller because the text is empty and we're no longer searching. If you **really** want to be sure, you can also ensure that `searchText.length == 0`.
3. `searchBar:textDidChange:` is invoked before `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`, which is why we handled it in this order.
4. I update the search results every time the text changes, but you may want to move the `[self.searchResultsUpdater updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self];` to `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` if you only want the search performed after the user presses the *Search* button.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift:**

The following worked for me, added under viewDidLoad, because I never wanted that button:

```
let searchBarStyle = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
searchBarStyle?.clearButtonMode = .never
```

Make sure to add the ID for the searchBar in the storyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use UISearchControllerDelegate.

```
func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {

        searchController.searchBar.setValue("", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
    }
```