# UISearchController cancel button not hiding & locking UISearchBar to top of UITableView?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, uikit

I have set up a UISearchController and works great. However, I don't want the Cancel button to appear when is active. It seems like XCode not responding to my method searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false.

Also, how can I lock the UISearchBar to the top of my UITableView when the UISearchController is not active?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS8 Cannot hide cancel button on search bar in UISearchController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769267/ios8-cannot-hide-cancel-button-on-search-bar-in-uisearchcontroller)

Answer (score -1):

To not show the cancel button you can execute the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
```

Then to lock your search bar to the top of the table view, just add a constraint of 0 from the search bar to the table view. Or if that doesn't work you can try putting the search bar inside of the table view(under it in the hierarchy) and then from there, you can add again a constraint of 0 to the top.

Comment: How can I add the constraint, because the UISearchController is added via the code (currently XCode not supporting it in Main.storyboard, right). Does that mean I have to add a constraint programmatically? In fact I have a UITableViewController because this view manages only tables, nothing else.

Comment: Huh, thats weird. The storyboard works fine for me. For adding constraints in code you could try an Api called Snapkit. Here's the link: https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry You could try using that.