# how to hide canncel button in searchBar navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

Acctualy, I have seen a lot of tutorials on here but it not still work. I really don't know why. My version iOS is 9.1. Now I really hate cancel button.

[image: This is my obnoxious canncel button]

*Here is my setup in Viewdidload()*

```
override func setViewWhenDidLoad() {
        titleNoSearch.text = "Không có câu hỏi nào được tìm thấy"
        //setup search bar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Tìm theo mô tả trong câu hỏi hoặc đáp án"

        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        TableSearchView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
        didPresentSearchController(searchController: searchController)
        // content search
        getContentSearchFullIndex()

    }

    func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    }
```

*And I try another way by overdrive some function*

```
class  setUISearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }

}


class CustomSearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var _searchBar: setUISearchBar = {
        [unowned self] in
        let result = setUISearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
        result.delegate = self

        return result
        }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return _searchBar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, what is this function `setViewWhenDidLoad()` you are overriding? did you mean `viewDidLoad()`? You also have `searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)` twice in the same function block.

Comment: I have a mistake about it, I'm just remove one setShowsCancelButton. You now how to remove Cancel button, are't you ?

Comment: refer this ans. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26769326/6822622

Comment: Searchbar have 1 delegate method use this func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    }